# NodeJs fetching google fit sleep data returning empty results

Tags: node.js, google-fit

I am trying to fetch sleep data from google fit, I am successfully getting response but the point key has nothing,which must include  sleep records objects if record exists in google fit.
My request format is something like below

```js
 var startDate = moment(new Date()).startOf('day').add("-10", "days");
 startDate = `${formatZuluTimeToIstdate(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}T00:00:00Z`;
 var startTimeMillis = new Date(startDate).getTime(); // unix timestamps 
 var endTimeMillis = getCurrentDate().getTime(); // unix timestamps
 var requestData = {
     "aggregateBy": [{
         dataTypeName: "com.google.sleep.segment",
     }],
     "endTimeMillis": endTimeMillis,
     "startTimeMillis": startTimeMillis,
 }

 const result = axios({
     method: "POST",

     url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate",
     headers: {
         "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
         "Content-Type": 'application/json',
     },

     data: requestData
 }).then(result => {
     console.log("result ====>", result);
 }).catch(error => {
     console.log("error", error)
 })
```

I already have more than 1 week of data and Trying to  fetch at least 10 days of data. but result is something like below
[image]

Comment: Does your query work when you try it [using the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate)?

Comment: @robertklep I tried to test on API explorer, Does it required all the params to test ? Because I tried using only few params and I put "me" in userId field, and Is giving me 403 issue. as in my problem I already resolved 403 issue.

Comment: Are you signed in on the website? I assume you have to be before you can use the API explorer. Also, if you press the square icon in the top right corner of the explorer sidebar, to enlarge it, it will show you how to make the request using `cURL`, which could also be helpful in trying to determine where exactly the issue occurs.

Comment: @robertklep , I Checked on that playground, I put "me" as userId but  I am getting , empty bucket=[] here for same user.

Comment: So the issue is with the API (or how you use it) and not so much with your code.

Comment: @robertklep, If my  code doesn't have problem, what will be better option except  querying to google?

Comment: Hope for someone to be able to help you here on SO, but it seems like a very specific issue.